# wp_enqueue_scripts are apearing inline rather than as links

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm not sure whats going on with my code here, I'm enqueuing scripts like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox', '/wp-content/themes/'.get_stylesheet() . '/js/lightbox.js');
```

However when I view the source of my page, the script isn't being linked, rather all the js is being loaded into the head of the document like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" style="display:none"><!--
/*!
 * Lightbox v2.9.0
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/LICENSE
 */
!function(a,b){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],b):"object"==typeof exports?
etc...
```

Is this the correct behavior? It seems to be causing conflicts with my other scripts? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use relative URLs when enqueuing media items. Use the full URL instead.

There are two functions that can come in handy: [`get_theme_file_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/) and [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/).

So:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/lightbox.js' ) );
```

will be the correct syntax.